# How to pass agruments to c++ program with exec() command?

Tags: php, exec

I have a c++ program that adds 2 numbers. I execute it with the `exec()` command in php. For this I need to pass 2 numbers to the program. How can I do this?

Here is the php code:

```
exec("test.exe", $output);
print_r($output);
```

EDIT:

I am getting -2 always when do the following:

```
exec("test.exe $number1 $number2", $output);
print_r($output);
```

No matter what the numbers are, I am getting -2 as the output. The program is fine because I have ran and tested it in command prompt.

EDIT 2:

Basically `test.exe` is a C++ program. The code is this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a,b;
    cin >> a >> b;
    cout << a+b;
    return 0;
}
```

In commmand prompt it works fine. Also I have tried the following:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Any string";
    return 0;
}
```

This program gives the correct output on using `echo exec("test.exe");`

Comment: Are the `$number` variables declared with the values before you try to make the call? What's the format that the `test.exe` needs the arguments in?

Comment: What if you change it to `$st = 'text.exe '.$number.' '.$number2; exec($st, $output);`?

Comment: This too doesn't help. I have mentioned the C++ code of the program above.

Comment: Ah, so they're not arguments, you want it to get the new information over `stdin` instead of the arguments when you call the program. In that case, you need to use [`proc_open`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) instead of `exec` because `exec` can't do what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This will solve my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the arguments like you'd do from shell:

```
exec("test.exe 5 7", $output);
```